# How to define day from 6am to 6am on x axis in ggplot?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a bar chart of an aggregate, by the hour.

```
hourly <- data.frame(
  hour = 0:23,
  N = 7+0:23,
  hour.mod = c(18:23, 0:17))
```

The day is from 6am to 6am, so I added an offset, hour.mod, and then:

```
ggplot(hourly, aes(x = hour.mod, y = N)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "6am to 6am", y = "Count")
```

Except, the x-axis scale at 0 contradicts the label. While tinkering with scales: `scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(6, 10, 14, 18, 22))` disappeared the scale altogether; which works for now but sub-optimal.

How do I specify x axis to start at an hour other than 0 or 23? Is there way to do so without creating an offset column? I am a novice, so please assume you are explaining to the village idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what you want to see, but it's fairly clear that you should be using `scale_x_continuous` and shifting your labels somehow, either "by hand" or with some simple math:

```
ggplot(hourly, aes(x = hour.mod, y = N)) +
   geom_col() +
   labs(x = "6am to 6am", y = "Count") + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(0,4,8,12,16), labels = c(6, 10, 14, 18, 22) )
```

Or perhaps:

```
ggplot(hourly, aes(x = hour.mod, y = N)) +
   geom_col() +
   labs(x = "6am to 6am", y = "Count") + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(6, 10, 14, 18, 22)-6, # shifts all values lower
                     labels = c(6, 10, 14, 18, 22) )
```

It's possible you need to use modulo arithmetic, which in R involves the use of `%%` and `%/%`:

```
1:24 %% 12
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  0
```

Comment: Thank you - this 'manual' solution serves my immediate purpose. Way better than by making the scale disappear with scale_x_discrete, which I was using because I recall reading somewhere that binned counts are discrete values. As for what I want to accomplish: the same chart but `hourly` only contains `hour` and `N`, no manually added `hour.mod`. Some way of defining x-axis 0 as hour 6, plot rest of the vector to 23, return to hour 0 and continue till it hits 6 again. That is, 6am is a "limit" at both ends - if that makes sense. In my head I'm treating it as a circular vector? A merry-go-round.